# Jquery find get value of hidden input by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that lists results using a while loop but I am struggling to get the value of the hidden input with the class `case_id` when the `class_btn` is clicked.

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="hidden" name="case_id" class="case_id" value="<? echo $case_id; ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="account_id" class="account_id" value="<? echo $account_id; ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="user_id" value="<? echo $diary_id; ?>" />
         <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
         <input type="button" name="class_btn" value="get class" />
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am using

```
case_id = $(this).prev('.case_id').val();
```

But all I keep getting is `undefined`

Comment: what is `$(this)` representing? is it the button?

Comment: the get class button.

Comment: I kow that is probably wrong nbut I have tried every which way I can think of

Comment: `$(this).closest("td").find('.case_id').val();` - `.prev` looks at the previous element, not previous until it finds the correct one.

Comment: @tymeJV thanks but still returns undefined

Comment: @tymeJV scratch that but it works fine, please add as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: How about `$("input[name=case_id]").val();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.prev` looks at the previous element, not previous until it finds the correct one. You should get the closest parent container, then find the element you're looking for.

```
$(this).closest("td").find('.case_id').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should use `prevAll` instead of `prev` since it is not the immediate adjacent sibling. `prevAll` [will list all preceding sibling elements](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and you can then filter those down.

```
case_id = $(this).prevAll('.case_id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
case_id = $(this).closest('td').find('.case_id').val();
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to access the value of `case_id` like so:

```
$('input[name=class_btn]').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().find('.case_id').val());
});
```

Comment: there will be multiple instances of the class 'case_id' coming from the while loop, so this actually wouldnt work